# Chrome Lighthouse result for LCP don't match the Performance tab values

Tags: performance, lighthouse

I'm running my app on localhost and I've been experiment with the Lighthouse tool to implement some optimizations. It's a statically built NextJS app, so it should be pretty fast.

This is the result I get with Lighthouse:

[image]

I have no idea what it's showing 4.8s for LCP and 4.5s for TTI.

When I click on `View Original Trace`, this is what I get:

[image]

What are the two values so different from each other? Is it beacuase it does network/device throttling by default?